# Unable to bring transparent background in image using adobe photoshop cs5,

Tags: image, photoshop

I am creating .gif progress bar using Adobe Photoshop CS5.  My client asked to keep progress bar like below.

[image]

I tried in Adobe and got below .gif image. But problem is I am unable to bring transparent background. I reduced opacity % in Photoshop it displaying correctly in Photoshop.

But when I saved as .gif then image background loss is transparent and I getting image like below.

[image]
I tried lot but unable to meet my client expectation.

Comment: http://www.ajaxload.info/ ?

Comment: @Strawberry: Not really answering the question about how to to it in photoshop, but nice site-tip anyways :D Looks handy!

Comment: Why use a spanner when you've got a hammer? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the option "Save for web & devices"? If so, you should be presented with alot of options (amongst those, transparency).

tutorial: http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/photoshop-basics/transparent-gifs-in-photoshop.8923.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Save for web option

> Alt+Shift+Ctrl+S

and select GIF, then enable transparency checkbox.

If the above method doesnt work, use this website
[loading.io](https://loading.io/)